# How to call dateutil.rrule.rrule's __str__ method

Tags: python, string

From the source code for [dateutil's rrule](http://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_modules/dateutil/rrule.html#rrule), I've noticed that the class `rrule` has its own `__str__` method defined. Hence it would expect that if I create an instance `my_rrule` of `rrule` and call `str(my_rrule)`, it would invoke that method. However, this seems not to be the case:

```
In [1]: from dateutil.rrule import *

In [2]: my_rrule = rrule(DAILY, count=2)

In [3]: str(my_rrule)
Out[3]: '<dateutil.rrule.rrule object at 0x7f97afed29d0>'
```

I would instead like to see something like what is described in the source code, namely "a string that would generate this RRULE if passed to rrulestr". How can I invoke the 'class-specific' `__str__` method instead of the 'default' one?

Comment: Do you perhaps mean `help(dateutil.rrule.rrule)`?

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce this issue. Which version of `dateutil` are you using? Try printing `dateutil.__version__` if you're not sure.

Comment: I'm using version 2.4.2. Following your comment below, I'm trying to upgrade to 2.6, but if I run the command `sudo apt-get install python-dateutil` from the command line, I get "python-dateutil is already the newest version (2.4.2-1)". Did you have to install version 2.6 'manually'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Updated answer**

As pointed out by Blckknight, before I was not using the most recent version of `dateutil`, namely 2.6.0 at the time of writing. With the newest version the string contains the information needed to reconstruct the `rrule`:

```
In [1]: from dateutil.rrule import *

In [2]: my_rrule = rrule(DAILY, count=2)

In [3]: str(my_rrule)
Out[3]: 'DTSTART:20161124T123554\nFREQ=DAILY;COUNT=2'

In [4]: import dateutil

In [5]: dateutil.__version__
Out[5]: '2.6.0'
```

**Old (incorrect) answer**

It would appear that the source code on http://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_modules/dateutil/rrule.html#rrule is from an older version of `rrule`. I downloaded the source code of dateutil 2.0 and searched in `rrule.py` for `__str__`, but found no results (see below).

[image]

P.S. Here is the definition of `__str__` in the docs I was referring to:

[image]

Comment: `dateutil` 2.0 is not the latest version. I get 2.6 when I install `python-dateutil` with `pip`. The docs exactly match the version I have installed.